# Programatically adding categories column to outlook vsto addin in C#

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

I am developing an Outlook Addin in which I am adding a category to a mail. In order add the category I am adding it first by clicking `VIEW` tab and then clicking on `Add Column` and then clicking on Categories, adding the "Categories" then pressing `OK`. Now I want to do this programmatically. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is. You need to customize the current view of the explorer or folder if you want to apply changes for every explorer window. To obtain a `View` object for the view of the current `Explorer` , use `Explorer.CurrentView` instead of the `CurrentView` property of the current `Folder` object returned by `Explorer.CurrentFolder`. You must save a reference to the `View` object returned by `CurrentView` before you proceed to use it for any purpose.

The `View` object allows you to create customizable views that allow you to better sort, group and ultimately view data of all different types. There are a variety of different view types that provide the flexibility needed to create and maintain your important data.

- The table view type ( `olTableView` ) allows you to view data in a simple field-based table.
- The Calendar view type ( `olCalendarView` ) allows you to view data in a calendar format.
- The card view type ( `olCardView` ) allows you to view data in a series of cards. Each card displays the information contained by the item and can be sorted.
- The icon view type ( `olIconView` ) allows you to view data as icons, similar to a Windows folder or explorer.
- The timeline view type ( `olTimelineView` ) allows you to view data as it is received in a customizable linear time line.

Views are defined and customized using the `View` object's [XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/a933daaa-370f-2ed3-0a59-86f766a1f2c8%28office.15%29.aspx) property. The `XML` property allows you to create and set a customized XML schema that defines the various features of a view.

The XML definition describes the view type by using a series of tags and keywords corresponding to various properties of the view itself. When the view is created, the XML definition is parsed to render the settings for the new view.

To determine how the XML should be structured when creating views, you can create a view by using the Outlook user interface and then you can retrieve the `XML` property for that view.

```
 Sub DisplayViewDef() 
   'Displays the XML definition of a View object 
   Dim objName As Outlook.NameSpace 
   Dim objViews As Outlook.Views 
   Dim objView As Outlook.View 

   Set objName = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI") 
   Set objViews = objName.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Views 

   'Return a view called Table View if it already exists, else create one 
   Set objView = objViews.Item("Table View") 
   If objView Is Nothing Then 
     Set objView = objViews.Add("Table View", olTableView, olViewSaveOptionAllFoldersOfType) 
   End If 
   MsgBox objView.XML 
 End Sub
```

To programmatically add a custom field to a view, use the [Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Outlook-VBA/articles/viewfields-add-method-outlook) method of the [ViewFields](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Outlook-VBA/articles/viewfields-object-outlook) object. This is the recommended way to dynamically change the view over setting the `XML` property of the `View` object.

Comment: Eugene I am developing this extension in c#. And the above code I tried it converting to c# and execute. It didn't help.

Comment: The Outlook object model is common for all kind of programming languages, so you need to understand what properties and methods to use for your task.

Answer (score 1):

In order to add custom fields you have to use ViewFields.Add as Eugene correctly described. But he did not state that finally you have to call Save() and Apply() on the view to apply the changes.

Sample in C# assuming we have an outlook application object:

```
View view = application.ActiveExplorer().CurrentView;
if (view is TableView tableView)
{
    tableView.ViewFields.Add("MyUserProperty");
    tableView.Save();
    tableView.Apply();
}
```

See more information on [Microsofts Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.view.save)